FSDP in Accelerate for Large-Context LLaMA Training
I'm trying to train a LLaMA model with large contexts using Hugging Face's Trainer, Fully Sharded Data Parallel (FSDP), and the accelerate library to handle memory limits. My context size is very large, with max token sizes over 70k. While my setup works fine for smaller context sizes, I'm hitting a roadblock with larger ones.
Here's a simplified version of my setup:
from transformers import pipeline, AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, Trainer, TrainingArguments
from datasets import Dataset

model_name = "meta-llama/Llama-3.2-1B"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, use_cache=False)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

dataset = load_dataset("my_private_dataset")

def tokenize_function(examples):
    tokenized = tokenizer(
        prompts,
        padding="max_length",
        truncation=True,
        max_length=70000
    )
    tokenized['labels'] = tokenized['input_ids']
    return tokenized

tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./results",
    num_train_epochs=5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    save_steps=5000,
    save_strategy="epoch",
    save_total_limit=1,
    logging_dir='./logs',
    logging_steps=1000,
    eval_strategy="no",
    gradient_checkpointing=True,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_dataset,
)

trainer.train()

When I try to train with accelerate for larger contexts, I get this error:

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (0) must match the size of tensor b (2048) at non-singleton dimension 2

I verified the batch sizes and tensor shapes for smaller inputs and single GPU, and everything looks correct. The error only appears when the input size gets large.
Questions:

Has anyone encountered this type of error specifically with FSDP or accelerate for large contexts?
Are there additional accelerate configurations or debugging steps for extremely large token sequences that could help identify the issue?
Is FSDP right method for large context?

